# Exuberant Ctags with R

Tags: r, vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

Is there any documented use of [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) with R?
Would this be useful?
Would it be difficult to implement?

Specifically, I've just started using Vim.
It would be cool to be able to write an R function in one file, use the function in another file (e.g., an Rnw file, test file, or some other script), and be able to use Ctrl+] to navigate to the function source.

**Update:** I've since stumbled on the [rtags](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/rtags.html) function. It is suggested [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67803527/180892) that it works with vim.

Answer (score 10):

This is a modification of Henrico's answer, and may be implemented by copying and pasting the following code into one's ~/.ctags files. Henrico's code did not work for indented functions, but the following code does.

```
--langdef=R
--langmap=r:.R.r
--regex-R=/^[ \t]*"?([.A-Za-z][.A-Za-z0-9_]*)"?[ \t]*<-[ \t]function/\1/f,Functions/
--regex-R=/^"?([.A-Za-z][.A-Za-z0-9_]*)"?[ \t]*<-[ \t][^f][^u][^n][^c][^t][^i][^o][^n]/\1/g,GlobalVars/ 
--regex-R=/[ \t]"?([.A-Za-z][.A-Za-z0-9_]*)"?[ \t]*<-[ \t][^f][^u][^n][^c][^t][^i][^o][^n]/\1/v,FunctionVariables/
```

This allows variables to be recognized with ctags as well as functions.  If you're using the taglist vim addon, then, it allows you to distinguish between global variables and other variables. Also, if you're using taglist, then you will need to paste the following in your vimrc.

```
let tlist_r_settings = 'R;f:Functions;g:GlobalVariables;v:FunctionVariables'
```

Comment: I think this answer is wrong! Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32206608/ctags-and-r-regex

Answer (score 9):

This is the content of my .ctags file in my home directory. I found it somewhere on the internet. Using this you can generate a tags-file for vim.

```
 --langdef=Splus
 --langmap=Splus:.s.S.R.r.q
 --regex-Splus=/^[ \t]+"?([.A-Za-z][.A-Za-z0-9_]*)"?[\t]*<-[\t]*function/\1/
 --regex-Splus=/^"?([.A-Za-z][.A-Za-z0-9_]*)"?[ \t]*<-/\1/
```

Comment: @shabbychef Because the language definition for functions and such is equal, there is no need to use a separate Ctags definition. Ofcourse, you can just change `--langdef=Splus` to `--langdef=R`.

Comment: Your edits aren't really appropriate, @LMZ - they change so much of Henrico's answer that it's not his answer any more. If you have a better solution, please post it as an answer of your own.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you can read [how to add support for a new language](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/EXTENDING.html) to ctags.

Comment: Thanks. I had a quick look at that. I've never used ctags, so it might be a bit of a learning curve. But I plan to get into it more.

Answer (score 3):

rtags() is the best to way to generate tags for R codes from what I see so far, since it will take all different ways of assignments in consideration, such as:

```
ok = c("<-", "=", "<<-", "assign",
       "setGeneric", "setGroupGeneric", "setMethod",
       "setClass", "setClassUnion")
```

An example of using rtags():

```
path <- "~/path/to/project"
rtags(path=path,
      pattern = "[.]*\\.[RrSs]$",
      keep.re = ".", # the value ('/R/') in the help page will only run through the codes in R/ folder.
      verbose = TRUE,
      ofile = file.path(path, 'TAGS'),
      append = FALSE,
      recursive = TRUE)
```

Comment: This is useful, how `rtags` output can be integrated with [tag:vim]?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by other `rtags()` + `etags2ctags()` can generate a `tagsfile` for vim (see `:h tags-and-searches`). You can create a custom command for vim so that it run `rtags()` in R using `Rscript`. To do so put this in your `.vimrc`:

```
:command! Rtags :!Rscript -e 'rtags(path="./", recursive=TRUE, ofile="RTAGS")' -e 'etags2ctags("RTAGS", "rtags")' -e 'unlink("RTAGS")'
set tags+=rtags
```

Now when you do `:Rtags` vim will run the external process `Rscript` (it has to be in the `PATH` of course) and evaluate `rtags(path="./", recursive=TRUE, ofile="RTAGS");etags2ctags("RTAGS", "rtags");unlink("RTAGS")`. `rtags()` will generate an `RTAGS` file in [Emacs tags format](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsTags#tags) then `etags2ctags()` will transform that into an `rtags` file which vim can read. `unlink()` deletes the `RTAGS` file since it's not needed for vim.

The `set tags+=rtags` makes vim to search for an `rtags` file in addition to the usual `tags` file (See `:h tags-and-searches`)

Answer (score 1):

[Universal-ctags](https://ctags.io) has an R parser.

```
$ cat input.r
add <- function (x, y) {
    3 -> z
    return(x + y + z)
}
add (3, 4)
$ ./ctags --quiet --options=NONE -o - --kinds-R='*' --fields=+S input.r
add input.r /^add <- function (x, y) {$/;"  f   signature:(x, y)
x   input.r /^add <- function (x, y) {$/;"  z   function:add
y   input.r /^add <- function (x, y) {$/;"  z   function:add
z   input.r /^    3 -> z$/;"    v   function:add
```

In addition, the ctags implementation supports R6Class and S4Class.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think `rtags()` works in vim.

I use the nvim-r plugin (available at https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2628), and have the following in my `~/.vimrc` file:

```
:command! Rtags :!Rscript -e 'rtags(path="./", recursive=TRUE, ofile="TAGS")'
```

With this setup, using `:Rtags` in vim rebuilds the tags, and then e.g. `g]` when the mouse is over a word finds the definitions for that word.